# i686-w64-mingw32-c++ compile with debug option on

Tags: debugging, winapi, g++, mingw

I'm trying to compile a really simple program with "i686-w64-mingw32-c++" and I tried to add the "-debug" flag but nothing changed.
How can I compile with debug information?

Comment: You cannot use GNU tooling and expect a sane development experience. It's rooted deep in wrong-decisions territory (*"all symbols are public by default"*, *"debug information must go into executable binaries"*, etc.).

Comment: @IInspectable Hello, actually I'm using linux so this is what I've got lol Maybe I'll install Windows 10 to develop Windows exes

Comment: So, I take it, you have zero interest in verifying that your programs actually do what you think they do? No testing, no debugging? Let's just say we probably have nothing in common. Good luck to you, you'll need it.

Comment: Actually I'm using ollydbg to debug exes and I'm debugging it without using Windows. Actually I'm doing Assembly exercises so I can debug it this way, when I'll need to install Windows for complex programs I will install it as I said . If you are a "person who debugs" why did u judge me without enough information about me? lol It's pretty funny for me.

Comment: Also for simple programs I normally just use a print instruction for debugging

Answer (score 3):

The flag you need is compiler `-g`. This will add debugging information.

When linking you should also make sure you don't strip the debugging information (make sure the linker flag `-s` is not used).

To see the full help use `-v --help` flags.

Comment: There's no "-g" option on i686-w64-mingw32-c++, when I try to use it I get the error: "i686-w64-mingw32-c++: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘--g’; did you mean ‘-Og’?".
I already used the "--help" command but there isn't information about the "-g" option. Also using "man" there's no reference to the "-g" option :/

Comment: This is the output of my version: └─$ i686-w64-mingw32-c++ --version >      
i686-w64-mingw32-c++ (GCC) 10-win32 20210110

Comment: It's not `--g` but `-g` and it should be listed in the extended help via `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -v --help`

Comment: As for version: latest GCC is 12.1.0. You can get my standalone build for Windows from: https://winlibs.com/

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't see I was using double "-" lol